# Rails 5 - link_to params Raises: Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

pretty simple link:

```
<%= link_to("Download CSV", params.merge(format: :csv) %>
```

raises:

> Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An
>   attacker can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as
>   changing the host. Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be
>   secure.

This has not raised errors in previous versions of rails.

Answer (score 2):

Wow - Answering my own question:

```
<%= link_to("Download CSV", params.permit(:product_ids).merge(format: :csv) %>
```

This is because of strong parameters

Comment: Wouldn't that still be unsafe if I used something like `/?product_ids=%22%3E%3Csvg%2Fonload%3Dconfirm(%2FXSS-IS-HERE%2F)%3E`